# How can i make a pdf of my html's content with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I'm doing a project where I have to create a pdf of the complete content with javascript. I have used jspdf up to now but it throws me errors with `<li>` elements (alignment), so i need another possibility to work. I need  to be able to give the full html content as a parameter. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nodejs wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf), it is built around for [wkhtml](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/).

Comment: Thanks for comment but i need some resource to use in web, not with webpack and nodejs